# The application may be doing too much work on its main thread room flow

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

when I run application on emulator it works fine but It open and close immediately on my phone and get this

```
W/Looper: Slow Looper main: Long Msg: seq=7 plan=13:35:52.606  late=267ms wall=1940ms running=0ms h=android.view.Choreographer$FrameHandler c=android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver
I/Choreographer: Skipped 220 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
W/Looper: Slow Looper main: doFrame is 1834ms late because of 4 msg, msg 1 took 1940ms (seq=7 late=267ms h=android.view.Choreographer$FrameHandler c=android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver), msg 4 took 81ms (seq=10 late=1757ms h=android.os.Handler c=androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 28010 SIG: 9
```

it was working fine,I don't know what happend but I am sure that the problem in room

dao

```
@Dao
interface WordDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM vocabulary_table ORDER BY last_revision ASC")
    fun get(): Flow<List<Vocabulary>>
}
```

repository

```
class VocabularyRepository(private val wordDao: WordDao) {
    val allVocabulary = wordDao.get()
}
```

viewModel

```
class HomeViewModel(application: Application):AndroidViewModel(application) {



    private val vocabularyRepository = getApplication<WordApplication>().vocabularyRepository
    val allVocabulary = vocabularyRepository.allVocabulary


}
```

compose function

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    onNavigateToForm:() -> Unit,
    onNavigateToReview:() -> Unit,
    onNavigateToSettings:() -> Unit,
    onNavigateToRecall:(id:Long) -> Unit
){
    val homeViewModel:HomeViewModel = viewModel()


    val allVocabulary = homeViewModel.allVocabulary.collectAsState(initial = emptyList())
    Text(allVocabulary.value.size.toString())

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewModel , you can make use of the viewModelScope and schedule the task on the IO thread to reduce the workload off the mainThread .

```
fun retreiveData(){
 viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
   // retreive data here
 }
}
```

Also , you can make use of `Profiler` to detect how is your main thread being utilized and then take action on the same .
The option to view Profiler is beside the Logcat . Just run your application by pressing the profiler icon(besides Debugger Icon) , and then watch how your main thread is being overused in the Profiler Section .